# Moving WCF service to IIS6 with SSL enabled

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I ran my WCF service on the server without SSL enabled and now I moved it to one with SSL enabled and I am getting the following error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

Below are my settings:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHTTP">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows">
        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="basicBehavior" name="ProjectName.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHTTP" contract="ProjectName.IMyService"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="basicBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by specifying security mode as `Transport` and using webHttpBinding

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a binding for basicHttps. This is a very simple settings that works for SSL:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
        address="https://MyURL/MyService.svc/soap/"
        binding="basicHttpsBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
        contract="ClientServiceReference.IMyService" />
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

**Note:** The *endpoint* needs to be defined and its URL is *https*.

Also, make sure that in production environment, you are not sending the exception details back to the caller (that would be considered a security hole in your system because exceptions can reveal too much information to hackers). You must change this line:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
```

Comment: look in the web.config file I posted in the original question